# how to read file for json file in ionic

Tags: json, mobile, ionic-framework

i am trying to get json file from url and display it in ionic and it is not working 
.i want the json data to display when the page loads, when i assign the data to a varable 
manually it works but when i try to do it from a url it does not load attall .

contoller.js class.

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('ChatsCtrl',function($scope,$http) {
 $scope.data = {};
  $scope.chats = $http.get('localhost/angl/file.json').success(function(res)){
   return res.data;
});

})
```

when i try it directlty like this it works

second controller.js class

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('ChatsCtrl',function($scope) {


  $scope.chats=[{
    id: 0,
    name: 'Ben Sparrow',
    lastText: 'You on your way?',
    face: 'img/ben.png'
  }, {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Max Lynx',
    lastText: 'Hey, it\'s me',
    face: 'img/max.png'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Adam Bradleyson',
    lastText: 'I should buy a boat',
    face: 'img/adam.jpg'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Perry Governor',
    lastText: 'Look at my mukluks!',
    face: 'img/perry.png'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Mike Harrington',
    lastText: 'This is wicked good ice cream.',
    face: 'img/mike.png'
  }];


})
```

but i want to read it from url help me

this is the error message i get

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (23:37:59:154 | error, network)
  at http://localhost:8383/someApp/cordova.js
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) (23:37:59:504 | error, javascript)
  at www/js/controllers.js:7
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter.controllers due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'starter.controllers' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/nomod?p0=starter.controllers
```

Comment: You want to display your JSON from res.data ? What do you have in the view ?

Comment: If it doesn't show at all then there should be error message in your console. It may be due to CORS. But just check your console and paste any error message here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.get('localhost/angl/file.json').success(function(res)){
     $scope.chats = res.data
});
```